# iOS6 flashlight does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flashlight

I'm trying to make hello-world-type app to learn how to turn on/off flashlight.
So there is only two buttons in this app: On and Off.
Here is action for "ON" button:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];
[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[device unlockForConfiguration];
```

It works fine on iOS7, but does not work on iOS6. What am I doing wrong?

UPD: [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn] does not work either

Comment: Are you sure your iOS 6 device got a led light?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some steps :

```
 - (void)toggleFlashlight
{
  AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff)
  {
    // Create an AV session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Create device input and add to current session
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create video output and add to current session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Start session configuration
    [session beginConfiguration];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    // Set torch to on
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [session commitConfiguration];

    // Start the session
    [session startRunning];

    // Keep the session around
    [self setAVSession:session];

    [output release];
  }
  else
  {
    [AVSession stopRunning];
    [AVSession release], AVSession = nil;
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you ;)

PS : Not my code - http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/flashlight-application-using-the-iphone-led.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't need AVSession (here it works with just this code http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2461qMQ7gUU)

Comment: Did you take his/her project and try it on the device you are trying your project to see if you get it works ? If yes then just check out the differences between your code and his/her

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in broken flashlight on my phone: even camera app did not take photo with flashlight. I should check such hardware problems first.